# Can you add the word "juste" to alter the nature of "trop ... pour"?

Tags: sens, usage

> Elles sont **trop** dénudées **pour** faire baver les hommes.
>
> == Elles sont trop dénudées, ce qui ne fait pas baver les hommes.

In this context, the use of "trop ... pour" does not make sense. But I wonder if the addition of "juste" changes the nature of the  "trop ... pour" construction:

> Elles sont **trop** dénudées **juste pour** faire baver les hommes.
>
> == Elles sont trop dénudées, tout simplement dans le but de faire baver les hommes.

Comment: You state that "**In this context**, the use of "trop ... pour" does not make sense," yet at the point where you make that statement I'm not sure that what "this context" is has been clearly established. If the context is "What level of feminine nudity makes men drool?" then couldn't the first, "trop dénudées pour," version make sense to describe a case where the men in question generally like/[or at least in this particular instance would have preferred] to have some things left to their imaginations? Regardless, couldn't the "dans le but de" sense be captured by just omitting the "trop"?

Comment: I would interpret your second sentence as "Elles sont trop dénudéesdans le seul but (uniquement dans le but) de faire baver les hommes." Jiliagre has a good suggestion.

Comment: Or "tout ça pour faire baver les hommes"

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a break in the sentence:

> Elles sont trop dénudées, [c'est] juste pour faire baver les hommes.

Answer (score 0):

Vous avez compris que l'ambiguïté porte sur le *trop ... pour*.
Si je reformule, les idées que vous voulez exprimer sont les suivantes :

- Elles sont trop dénudées.
- Elles sont dénudées pour faire baver les hommes.

Et en fusionnant les deux phrases, vous changez complètement le sens de ce que vous voulez dire.
La suggestion de Jiliagre peut convenir, mais il faut bien insister sur le "juste" :

> Elles sont trop dénudées, **juste** pour faire baver les hommes.

Sinon, il y a d'autres possibilités plus explicites :

> Si elles sont tellement dénudées, c'est juste pour faire baver les hommes.
>   Juste pour faire baver les hommes, elles sont trop dénudées.